# How to Exact match a value in raw string

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to create a function which match the exact value in the raw string if macthes then paste the value but here Lookup function is giving an wrong answer.

I know how to extract it using Left function but how to macth exact string like in VBA we use Criteria: "*" & CellValue & "*".

```
=LOOKUP(99^99,SEARCH($K$3:$K$97,A3),$K$3:$K$97)
```

This function is not matching exact string as you can see in attached picture.

[image]

Comment: Your method fails once the string in column A contains a valid state abbreviation. OR is part of Lorain. You are better of finding the first comma or space and cutting a string with a length of 2 letters based of the numeric value of the position found...

Comment: I undersntand your point but the data i have shared is in neat sequence but the data i could not share is totally a mess so thats why looking for that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

book ends the values with spaces, and lookup is probably not the best tool for this:

```
=INDEX($K:$K,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($K$3:$K$97)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&$K$3:$K$97&" "," "&A3&" "))),1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much similar to this if i want to do this using VBA with the fast way because i have data with more than 500K rows where formulas goes stuck and takes very long time to perform this.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: As i requested yesterday about slow response of the formula. is there any way to speed it up. I have alot of data where i need to apply this function. I would appreciate your help. @Scott Craner

Comment: This is not a code for me site. I helped with the correct formula because you showed what you tried.  If you want true vba help you will need to show what you tried and where it errors.

Comment: Alright Thank you very much i will post an question with my try. Thnaks